# How do I reduce the size of mlocate database?

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage, locate

I'm out of space on /var

```
  25G   25G     0 100% /var
```

It looks like mlocate.db is the problem:

```
# find /var -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head
13140140032 ./lib/mlocate/mlocate.db.cgLMAM
12409839616 ./lib/mlocate/mlocate.db.MqGeqe

# cat /etc/updatedb.conf
PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS="yes"
PRUNENAMES=".git .bzr .hg .svn"
PRUNEPATHS="/tmp /var/spool /media"
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 rpc_pipefs afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre_lite tmpfs usbfs udf"
```

I don't see anything else to prune. So how can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: WOW! that is more than 10GB each!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db.??????` files are leftover temporary files from a (probably) interrupted `updatedb` run. They don't appear on either of my Ubuntu 11.10 systems, except when `updatedb` is running. Delete them:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db.??????
```

then, to be sure, run

```
sudo /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
```

Comment: thank you.  i was debating whether or not to delete the 900+MB file `mlocate.db.pm5NNC` that was time stamped dec 2015.  with your answer i took the plunge!

Comment: clearly my nearly 1GB file was a little one and i've got off lightly: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1487312

Answer (score 0):

You can re-install it too:

```
apt remove --purge mlocate \
&& apt install mlocate
```

It will delete and recreate your `/var/lib/mlocate` database file.